# Adding database and schema for a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to ask how to print the database and schema name of a table for the '@tablename' variable?  It's because the update is simply just saying the table name like 'Baggage' and Baggage could be in either 'DB1.dbo.Baggage' or 'DB2.dbo.Baggage', so I want the correct database and schema to be retrieved.

```
    select @tablename = ''
        select @tablename = Value

        print 'update ' + @tablename + '
                        set ' + @update + '
                        ' + @whereClause  +  isnull(@addnlClause, '') + '
                        if @@ROWCOUNT <> 1 
                            BEGIN
                                THROW 99999, ''Error - Single Row not updated, rollback terminated'', 1;
                            END'
                        set nocount off
```

UPDATE:

Ok so lets say I have a database called 'SupportAudit' which contains all the procs. I have a database called 'Holidays' which contains its own tables, and another database called 'Reservations' containing its own tables. Below are examples of the tables these databases could have:

**Holidays**

dbo.Package

dbo.Product

Search.FlightList

Support.DataInputList

---

**Reservations**

dbo.Package

dbo.ProductPerson

Search.ProviderList

Support.DateRange

---

Now usually in our procs, when we refer to these tables, we refer to them as [database].[schema].[tablename]. e.g. [Holidays].[dbo].[Package] or [Reservations].[Support].[DateRange].

Now in the update which is only a print, we are trying to perform a rollback to our last update, so we want the print to reference to the exact table we want to update, to do this we need the exact table by using the [database].[schema].[tablename] method.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: In your example, the schema is dbo in both cases.  It's the database name that is variable.  If you find yourself in a situation where you are trying to determine what database you are in after you have connected to it, maybe it's time to step back and look at other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use DB_NAME() something like this -

```
SET @tablename = DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + Value
```

But, I really wouldn't do what you look like you're trying; an 'update any table' routine is one of those classic anti-patterns in SQL. Bad performance over time, harder to keep track of what's doing what and keep it in sync with other changes. Update sprocs for each distinct job really are a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, can I ask what is the global name for schema as it may not be a .dbo table?

Comment: Actually sorry, I am on a database called 'DBSupport', but I want to be able to call on either database 'DB1' or 'DB2' depending on which one it is in

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're asking; dbo is your default schema, and which SQL Server assumes (with a performance cost) if you don't specify one. You're passing in the table name somewhere to your code; the schema name should really go as a parameter alongside that if possible. If you really can't do that then as long as the table names are unique and not repeated across schemas, you could look it up from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. But I'd definitely pass it in if possible - safer and faster.

Comment: Ah, OK. How does your application know where the table is at present? Again the INFORMATION_SCHEMA solution is possible if you create a view that aggregates views across the databases, but again it's slower and less safe. I really would set up three input parameters - DB, Schema and Table.